# Changing CSS on disabled selected elements

Tags: css, forms, dropdown, disabled-input

I have a form with code similar to:

```
<form class="eng-select" action="action.php" method="POST">
    <select name="position">
        <option value="disabled" disabled selected>Engineer</option>
        <option value="entry-1">John Doe</option>
        <option value="entry-2">David Smith</option>
        <option value="entry-3">Michael Silk</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Which produces a dropdown like this:

[image: dropdown field]

However I would like to change the css color of the disabled selected entry (what the user sees when they load the page - the picture above). Is this possible, and if so what would the proper CSS call be?

I have looked at similar posts for IE here that mention:

```
select option [disabled] { background-color: blue; }
```

but this does not work for me (I am using Google Chrome).

To clarify - I would like to change the CSS **before** the user clicks and opens the dropdown box.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS must be

```
select option[disabled] { background-color: blue; }
```

Without the space after `option`. It should work better this way.

With the space, it applies to descendants of the `option`.

Comment: ha the deleted post seems to work better - the pseudo-class `:disabled` works on ie where as this doesn't: https://jsfiddle.net/o7rmzn2s/1/

Comment: For more compatibility, you may do both : `select option[disabled], select option:disabled`

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment, I'm looking for CSS changes to the existing dropdown (before the user has clicked it). I've tried this code but it only changes the disabled entry after the dropdown is opened. Is there a way to change it before the user clicks and opens the menu?

Comment: @Beep I think the natural behaviour of chrome  is to only apply any styling once you start hovering the drop down, if you want to properly style a select, you will need to use some sort of js plugin as `select`s are very limited in what you can actually style

Answer (score 0):

**use below css for disabled select  option**

```css
select option:disabled {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<form class="eng-select" action="action.php" method="POST">
    <select name="position">
        <option value="disabled" disabled selected>Engineer</option>
        <option value="entry-1">John Doe</option>
        <option value="entry-2">David Smith</option>
        <option value="entry-3">Michael Silk</option>
    </select>
</form>
```